# Species of this White Dove

Tags: zoology, species-identification

I visited a bird enclosure close to where I live in Australia. The enclosure had several different species. The birds that stood out most were these doves sitting right along the fence railing, making a deep "Wo-wo-wo-woo" sound. That and also I thought they looked and sounded similar to Spotted Doves.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know what the species of this birds may be?

Comment: if you still have any doubts or need any sort of clarification feel free to comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a Barbary dove (or Ringneck dove). See this image (from the [here](http://nzbirdsonline.org.nz/species/barbary-dove)):

[image]

More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_dove) and [here](http://nzbirdsonline.org.nz/species/barbary-dove). The second pages shows also images of different color variations.

Comment: I accepted @agha rehan abbas before, but only because I didn't see your answer. The Barbary Dove seems to have a white and brown wing tip, while the Collared Dove has solid colour for it's wingtip. The one I saw has the same type of pattern on it's wingtip.

Answer (score 1):

it is symi bird and more over it is commonly called as collared dove its a resident of symi and would have brought to australia by other means
[image]
you can find a list off all the symi birds [here](http://symifloraandfauna.jigsy.com/symibirdlist)